# How to implement synchronised Java method

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronized

I am new to multithreading and am trying to create a multithreading java booking system. An agent can reserve a seat and has the choice of multiple airlines. This is my Agent class:

```
public class Agent implements Runnable {
private int id;
private Reservation reservation;

public Agent() {

}

public Agent(Reservation reservation) {
    this.reservation = reservation;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        reservation.reserveSeat();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The reserveSeat is a synchronised method in the the Reservation class and is as such:

```
public synchronized boolean reserveSeat() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " entered.");

    List<Seat> availableSeats = airline.getAvailableSeats();

    // if there are no available seats
    while (availableSeats.isEmpty())
        wait();

    Seat seat;
    // repeat this until an available seat is chosen
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        do {
            System.out.println("Please choose from the following available seats: ");
            for (Seat s : availableSeats) {
                System.out.print(s.getNumber() + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();

            String input = reader.readLine();
            int seatNum = Integer.parseInt(input);
            seat = airline.getSeatObjectWithNumber(seatNum);
        } while (!availableSeats.contains(seat));

        this.seat = seat;

        // enter passenger details
        System.out.println("Please enter the passenger's name. ");
        // create passenger instance
        String name = reader.readLine();
        this.passenger = new Passenger(name);

        // change seat status to reserved
        seat.setReserved(true);

        // add this reservation to the list of reservations the airline has
        airline.getReservations().add(this);

        notifyAll();

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " leaving.");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

I am then trying to test my code in my main method by creating two agent instances that each try to make a reservation:

```
    Reservation reservation1 = new Reservation(airline1);
    Agent agent1 = new Agent(reservation1);
    new Thread(agent1).start();

    Reservation reservation2 = new Reservation(airline2);
    Agent agent2 = new Agent(reservation2);
    new Thread(agent2).start();
```

However, for some reason the output looks like this:

```
Thread-0 entered.
Thread-1 entered.
Please choose from the following available seats: 
1 2 3 
Please choose from the following available seats: 
1 2 3
```

I am not sure why the first thread Thread-0 is not blocking Thread-1 from entering the monitor. Like I said I am new to multithreading in Java and would really appreciate some guidance, thanks.

Comment: You're instantiating two separate Reservation classes, so the two threads aren't competing.  Try instantiating one reservation class and give it to both agents.

Comment: That works, thanks @BradBales! Although within this example I think it makes more sense to create new Reservation instances for each reservation and and create a new ReservationSystem class with a synchronised method that takes a reservation instance as a parametre as @Andy Thomas suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronized methods *on the same object* cannot be run at the same time.

You have two different Reservation objects. Their synchronization is independent of each other.

One way to fix this would be to create a `ReservationSystem` class with a synchronized method to reserve a seat -- and create one instance of it for multiple Reservation instances.

```
public class ReservationSystem {
   public synchronized boolean reserveSeat( Reservation reservation ) {
      ...
   }
}
```

From the [Java tutorial on synchronized methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html), with added emphasis:

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods **on the same object** to interleave. When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.